# 403 (Forbidden) error in opencart home page

Tags: php, opencart, http-status-code-403

> http://cloone.my/demo/symbol/v6/image/ 403 (Forbidden)

I have this error only in Opencart home page. The error only appears on the home page but on the rest of the pages, i don't see this error in console.
I tried to change permissions to 755 and 0777 nothing changed.

here is the attached screenshot:

[image: Screenshot image]

Comment: Why you are requesting the `dir` instead of a file in that dir?

Comment: I am not requesting any directory. Suddenly when i check my console its populating those errors.  Before its working fine later i don't know what happened.

Comment: Yea, but see that the GET request is for `http://.../v6/image/` instead of `http://.../v6/image/some-img.png`? usually requests pointing for directories fail due to the server forbidding directory listing.